# dictionary from multi-index groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5], 'b': [0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0], 'v': [2,4,3,7,6,5,9,3,2,4,5,2,3]})
>>> df
    a  b  v
0   1  0  2
1   1  1  4
2   1  1  3
3   2  0  7
4   2  1  6
5   3  0  5
6   3  0  9
7   3  1  3
8   3  1  2
9   4  1  4
10  4  0  5
11  5  1  2
12  5  0  3
>>> df.groupby(by =['a', 'b']).groups
{(2, 0): [3], (5, 0): [12], (3, 0): [5, 6], (5, 1): [11], (1, 0): [0], (3, 1): [7, 8], (4, 1): [9], (1, 1): [1, 2], (2, 1): [4], (4, 0): [10]}
```

q1. How can I get a dictionary that instead of the indices of each group would return the values of `column v` of each group?

q2. Is there a way to get a nested such dictionary?

```
{1: {0:[2], 1: [4,3]}, 2: {0: [7], 1: [6]} ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should using `to_dict`

```
df.groupby(by =['a', 'b']).v.apply(list).unstack().to_dict('index')
Out[1042]: 
{1: {0: [2], 1: [4, 3]},
 2: {0: [7], 1: [6]},
 3: {0: [5, 9], 1: [3, 2]},
 4: {0: [5], 1: [4]},
 5: {0: [3], 1: [2]}}
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer to q1 would be to omit `unstack()` and `'index'` from your solution, correct? Do you agree or is there another way?

Comment: @Tony yes q1 do not need unstack

Comment: If the `b` column has more than 2 values, even if they don't always appear in all `a` categories, these end up having a key value in each `a` subdictionary and `None` as their value, eg. if `3` appears once in the `b` `col` then `Out:` `{1: {0: [2], 1: [4, 3], 3: None}, 2: {0: [7], 1: [6], 3: None},...}` Any easy way to address this or should I open a new question? Thank you

Comment: @Tony Umm let us open a new issue :-)